# I'd like to create a array of record (Pascal) in Python. But how?

Tags: python, data-structures

Here my code:

```
class typeE:
    def __init__(self):
        self.u = 0
        self.v = 0
        self.w = 0


def readData():
    global n
    global m
    global e
    e = [typeE]
    c = -2
    f = open(fi, 'r')
    for line in f:
        print e[0]
        c += 1
        ln = [int(i) for i in line.split()]
        if c == -1:
            n = ln[0]
            m = ln[1]
        else:
            e[c].u = ln[0]
            e[c].v = ln[1]
            e[c].w = ln[2]
    f.close()
```

Do you have any idea how to make a record like this in Python?

```
type
      typeE = record
                  u, v, w: longint;
      end;
```

Comment: Your English is not the problem. What are you trying to achieve? What do you want to do with this data structure?

Comment: Is `fi` a filename, in which case enclose it in quotes, or a variable, in which case it is undefined.

Comment: `e = [typeE]` should probably be `e = [typeE()]`.  To add an element to a list, use `e.append(typeE())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is not Pascal. You don't create an "array of records" but a "list of objects" (which can be instances custom class, but in your case could as well be plain `dict`s).

Also, globals are a bad idea whatever the language, it's always better to use true functions (functions that return a result depending on their input, instead of mutating or rebinding global variables).

The pythonic version of your code (error handling set aside) would look something like this:

```
class TypeE(object):
    def __init__(self, u=0, v=0, w=0):
        self.u = u
        self.v = v
        self.w = w

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<TypeE({u}, {v}, {w})>".format(**self.__dict__) 

def to_int(line):
    return [int(i) for i in line.strip().split()]

def read_data(src):
    records = []

    with open(src, 'r') as f:
        headers = to_int(f.next())[:2]
        for line in f:
            records.append(TypeE(*ln[:3]))

    return headers, records

def main():
    (m,n), e = read_data("/path/to/your/file")
    # now do something with m, n and e
    print m, n, e

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```